# App crashes after switching night mode and mediaplayer stops

Tags: android, android-studio, android-night-mode

I have created an audio player app using Media Player, which streams a url from a JSON file. Everything works fine when switching UI mode (night mode to day mode & day mode to night mode), but it stops playing audio if I set datasource again then it crashes.

After Googling I found a solution, I did some changes in the manifest.xml file:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Now the media player is working properly, but I have to face another issue:

[image]

[image]

Some text color is matched with the background color and this issue comes up when I switch system UI mode to night mode after opening the app. If I open the app and scroll to the last item and then switch mode to night mode then this issue does not come up.

**I am not sharing any code snippet here, as I have no idea which code I should share.**

Comment: It's in an xml file called row something, located in your res/layout/ folder. Set a textColor inside your TextView. That should fix your problem.

Comment: You have to share `adapter`, `layout` source code.

Comment: if i set text color to white then its totaly disappear in day mode or if change to black then its disappear in night mode

Comment: Due to activity recreated(restart), while you change your UI mode(Dark to light or light to dark), you should manage your media playing from service class.

Comment: configChanges="uiMode" works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could solve your problem...

```
@Override
    protected void onNightModeChanged(int mode) {
        super.onNightModeChanged(mode);
    }
```

Comment: here should i set theme? or change text color